# I cant debug flutter project, beginner

Tags: flutter, provider, state-management

I am a Flutter beginner and trying to learn provider state management. I was using a tutorial online, and I have an issue that I came across. I have been trying to solve for days now, kindly clone [this GitHub project](https://github.com/ishyley/grocery_store_flutter_provider.git). the product for sale is supposed to be added to the cart when I click on the price on the homepage but I don't know why it is not. what am I doing wrong?